# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given open:

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Facebook login I am performing with OAuth2, and then I am using Laravel 4's built in Authentication system to log the user back in on revisit.  For the majority of users, I see no issues with what I have, but for one user, he is seeing the following error appear on login:

```
ErrorException
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given
open: */nfs/c09/h04/mnt/139243/domains/crowdsets.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php
*        /**
        * Log a user into the application.
        *
        * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface  $user
        * @param  bool  $remember
        * @return void
        */
       public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)
       {
               $id = $user->getAuthIdentifier();
```

Here is the relevant login/authentication code in the controller:

```
$check = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $user['uid'])->first();

                if(is_null($check)) {

                  $fan = new Fan;

                  $fan->fbid = $user['uid'];
                  $fan->email = $user['email'];
                  $fan->first_name = $user['first_name'];
                  $fan->last_name = $user['last_name'];
                  $fan->gender = $user['gender'];
                  $fan->birthday = $user['birthday'];
                  $fan->age = $age;
                  $fan->city = $city;
                  $fan->state = $state_abbrev;
                  $fan->image = $user['image'];
                  $fan->friend_ids_url = $user['friends'];
                  $fan->friend_ids_unpacked = $friend_ids;

                  $fan->save();

                  $new = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $user['uid'])->first();

                  Auth::login($new);
                  return Redirect::to('fans/home');

                }

               else {

                  Auth::login($check);

                  $fan = Fan::find(Auth::user()->id);
                  $fan->image = $user['image'];
                  $fan->save();

                  return Redirect::to('fans/home');
                  var_dump($user);

               }
```

This is my code in the model for the table I am using to keep user information, called "Fans":

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class Fan extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function getAuthIdentifier() 
{ 
return $this->getKey(); 
}


public function getAuthPassword() 
{ 
return $this->password; 
}
```

This is very perplexing because this login works for all of the other profiles I have tried.  It is only with this friend's profile that it is throwing this error.  I will also add, that on login (or retries) it will create multiple entries for this user in the database/table.  This authentication system is supposed to be set up to prevent exactly this.  Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you get it resolved? if yes, will you please share your thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

in the create() method in the LoginController you must return the $user

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);

        return $user;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Try refactor your code to this:

```
$fan = Fan::where('fbid', '=', $user['uid'])->first();

if (is_null($fan)) {
    $fan = new Fan;

    $fan->fbid = $user['uid'];
    $fan->email = $user['email'];
    $fan->first_name = $user['first_name'];
    $fan->last_name = $user['last_name'];
    $fan->gender = $user['gender'];
    $fan->birthday = $user['birthday'];
    $fan->age = $age;
    $fan->city = $city;
    $fan->state = $state_abbrev;
    $fan->image = $user['image'];
    $fan->friend_ids_url = $user['friends'];
    $fan->friend_ids_unpacked = $friend_ids;

    $fan->save();
} else {
    $fan->image = $user['image'];
    $fan->save();
}

Auth::loginUsingId($fan->getAuthIdentifier());
return Redirect::to('fans/home');
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple question and the answer:
**Does your `Fan` class extend `User` class (or implements `UserInterface`)?**
If not, then the simplest way to fix this is

```
class Fan extends User{
    ....
}
```

Comment: as you can see above I have it implement UserInterface per this line:  use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class Fan extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {

Comment: I also already have the Fan class extending Eloquent...any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Auth::login($check);` or `Auth::login($new);` you should pass,

```
Auth::login(Auth::user());
```

The Auth::login() function accept the first parameter as UserInterface Object like `public function login(UserInterface $user, $remember = false)` and in the function body, this will take `userid` like this `$id = $user->getAuthIdentifier();`

Read API Doc [here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Guard.html#325-355).

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error on login:  Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given

Comment: As I said before, using the $check and $new values is working for the majority of users.  I have only recently seen this error with 1 user.

Answer (score 0):

try this. I solved my own.

```
$fan = User:where('id',$socialUser->getId())->first();
if(!$fan){
   **$fan** = User:create([
        'facebook_id' => $socialUser->getId(),
        'email' => $socialUser->getEmail()
   ]);
auth()->login($fan);
return return->to('whereYouLike');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I managed to resolve it by checking few things:

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given open:`

- As you can see, `null given` means that the `$user` you want to `Auth::login($user)` is null. Check if the variable it set.
- Don't put any `var_dump()` between the Auth::login and the final redirect(). It may stop the Authentification.

Hope it helps