# Invalid login throws: Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() > must implement interface

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

When I successfully login there is no problem I just get logged in. But when I type the wrong credentials it gives me this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login()
>   must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable,
>   null given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php
>   on line 294

This is my login controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use \Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Account;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    public function login()
    {
     $user = Account::where('email', request()->email)


           ->where('password',bcrypt(request()->password))
              ->first();
     Auth::login($user);
     return redirect('/');
 }
}
```

My Account (user) model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;

class Account extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use AuthenticableTrait;
    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [


 'username', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://github.com/cmgmyr/laravel-messenger/issues/82) issue in Github and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039870/argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-auth-guardlogin-must-implement-interface-ill?rq=1) post in SO?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, null given open:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039870/argument-1-passed-to-illuminate-auth-guardlogin-must-implement-interface-ill)

Comment: Well the answers on there don't work for me