# Login to using another API in server in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an
>   Instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   Illuminate\Http\Request given

Comment: Do you describe, what is your problem, and how you find it?

Comment: Did you refer to this already ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46037390/5928015

Comment: Please share the api method which you're trying to call seems like problem is with return statement

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very descriptive. But from the title and the error, I am assuming you are trying to login to your application using another application login API.

For that, you need to build your own custom authentication system, middlewares for protecting authorized routes etc.,  as laravel default `Auth` will not work since it depends on `Authenticatable` contract which in return depends on `user` modal of the applicaiton.

If that another API, happened to be one of the Social media, in that case, you can use `socialite driver`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function userlogin(Request $request){
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
                        'email' => 'required|max:255',
                        'pwd'   => 'required|max:255|min:3',
                        ]);

    $data = [   "username"=>$request->email,
                "password"=>$request->pwd,
            ]; 

    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/getuus/login");           

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type:application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $result = collect(json_decode($result));

    if ($result['status'] == 1) {
        $Auth = new Auth;   $Auth::login($request, true);
        return redirect('home');           
    }
    else{

        return view('userlogin');
    }

}
```

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;